# Password encryption method never returns the same result for the same parameters

Tags: java, security, encryption, passwords

I have [found](http://jerryorr.blogspot.fr/2012/05/secure-password-storage-lots-of-donts.html) code leveraging `java.security.*` in order to encrypt passwords. But when I use it, It's not working. Each time I call the encrypt method with the same parameters (which are displayed in the `encrypt()` method, and are really each time the same), I get a different result, which of course makes the code useless. Here my code:

```
public byte[] encrypt(String clearPassword, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    System.out.println(clearPassword+"     **********     "+salt);
    String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    int derivedKeyLength = 1600;
    int iterations = 20000;

    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(clearPassword.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    byte [] truc = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    System.out.println(truc);
    return truc;
}

public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    return salt;
}
```

I think I introduced an error in the original code at some point, but I can't see where. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post sample output and the calling code? Are you generating a new salt, based on a self-seeded PRNG, each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `System.out.println(truc);` does not do what you think it does. If you tried:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(truc));
```

you would print the actual content of the array, which should be the same every time you call the method with the same parameters.

See for example: [printing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964598/printing-arrays)

Comment: The worst is I got remembered to it this very morning. Sometimes I feel dumb. Thank you, assylias

Comment: There's also the possibility that he's feeding different salts to `encrypt`.

Comment: @chrylis He says that the parameters are the same based on the first println statement, so it is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: @assylias Well, he said that, but he's also printing the JVM ID of the `salt` array in that statement...

Comment: @assylias: I already checked the result using Arrays.toString(), and you're is right. I'm just waiting the SO mandatory 5 minutes to accept your answer...